# Set Spinner Adapter without calling onItemSelected

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

My codes goes like this.

```
spinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
chosenPosition = position;
spinner.setEnabled(false);
}
```

My intention is to save the position chosen by user and store it and immediately disable the spinner. But, when I set the Adapter, the first item automatically gets selected and the spinner gets disabled. How do I prevent it from calling the onItemSelected method when the Adapter is set?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a flag on top such as :

```
boolean isFirstSelection = true;
```

and in your onItemSelected method:

```
spinner.setEnabled(isFirstSelection);
if(isFirstSelection)    {
     isFirstSelection = !isFirstSelection;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped.